# Why doesn't it print the string?

Tags: c

it prints only FG and other characters are garbage

```
#include<stdio.h>

void putstr(char *s1[])
{
    while(*s1!='\0')
    {
      printf("%c",*s1);s1++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char s1[10]="fedfgh";
    putstr(s1);
}
```

Comment: I fixed your formatting. You may want to check your keyboard, the newline key seems to have gotten stuck :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`void putstr(char *s1[])` This is wrong. The actual argument to `putstr` is an array (which decays to a pointer) but the formal parameter says `putstr` accepts an array of pointers to `char`.

Use `void putstr(char *s1)` or `void putstr(char s1[])`.